# how make a new line character from XML to be detected if passing from ArrayList into excel?

Tags: java, excel, xml-parsing, apache-poi

I need some help to pass multi line text that I stored in ArrayLists into Excel cells. I made a parser to get values from each tag and now i'm trying to build my excel but I faced a problem that text from tags like this

```
<ProgramName>Mirror \n 2017</ProgramName>
```

looks like this `Mirror \\n 2017`if I manually copy it into setCellValue and I thinks this double slash is my problem but I have no idea why it's even here. and my code can't make it into a new line

```
    //progName style
    CellStyle cs = wb.createCellStyle();
    cs.setWrapText(true);
    cs.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
    cs.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

   //progName text
    Row row = sheet1.createRow((short) 1);
    Cell cell = row.createCell((short) 1);
    row.setHeightInPoints((2*sheet1.getDefaultRowHeightInPoints()));
    String asd = String.valueOf(ProgramName.get(0));
    cell.setCellValue(asd);
    sheet1.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(1,1,1,8));
```

Comment: The two characters ``\`` and `n` are not a newline character in XML. Only languages like C, Java, Javascript, ... treat it as such, and then only in literals. If you're reading text that contain character sequences like that, and want it treated as a newline character, then you need to decode it, e.g. with `replaceAll()` call, and using a third-party library with java string decode helper method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to Andreas

```
String asd = String.valueOf(ProgramName.get(0)).replaceAll("\\\\n", "\n");
```